# how to show mobile data usage in MB?

Tags: java, android

Is there any guides to show current total mobile data usage in MB? I know there are some example to show data track in bytes send and received..

Any helps would be appreciate 
Regards

Answer (score 2):

you can use [TrafficStats](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/TrafficStats.html)

The API is very simple, and simply gives you the total bytes received/sent, so you'll have to do some more work to keep track of hourly/daily/monthly stats. Well, that all depends on your needs.